# How to switch NavigationSplitView 2column or 3column

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I switch the content of the following view using an if statement or any other method?

How can I switch between the following two?

```
NavigationSplitView {

} detail: {

}

NavigationSplitView {

} content: {

} detail: {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Use a if statement

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var use2Column: bool = false
    @State private var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
    var body: some View {
        Group {
        if use2Column {
            NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
                // sidebar
            } detail: {
                // detail
            }
        } else {
            NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
                // sidebar
            } content: {
                // content
            } detail: {
                // detail
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
}
```

}

Though it may/may not be smooth transition depending on the size of data displayed